# How to change object orders?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I was wondering if I can change order of objects because of my animation exporter script only exports their transformation data with their index number -not names. I do it for efficiency in my game, in that way instead of using dictionary classes I use arrays.

I tried copying, deleting then pasting back but it didn't work. I need a simple way of doing this but if someone can show me a script to reorder it's also appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

No, if you rely on a specific order you will have to sort on export.

Comment: Looks like it's gonna be huge headache...

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing same problem.  I'm using blender for both my 3d scene, and a 2D GUI overlay.  For the solid GUI objects, I can just set the object's depth value, and let the z-buffer sort it out.  However, this trick does not work for semi-transparent objects (alpha-blended), which causes nasty artifacts.
I found a workaround, but you're not going to like it:
it is possible to re-order objects in the outliner, but this doesn't help, since they are still exported in alphabetical order.  So the only solution that works for me, is to rename all my objects to the letters of the alphabet, in the order that I want them rendered.